# Array to string conversion failed in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have a query which fetches distinct user ids and I am trying to convert it into a comma separated string which I can pass into another sql query having IN  in WHERE clause.
But I am getting an error saying array to string conversion.

```
$qry0="SELECT DISTINCT id FROM users  ";
$res0=getData($qry0);
while($row0=mysqli_fetch_array($res0))
{
    $data0      =   $row0['id'];  
}
```

And I'm trying to convert it as string like this:

```
$array = explode(",", $data0);
```

and pass it to another

```
$qry="SELECT * FROM login WHERE clientid IN(".$array.") ";
```

Comment: `explode` creates an array. where `implode` creates a string ... an SQL query requires a string, not an array.

Comment: $data0 is not an array.It is a variable with last value of id from your loop .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

USe implode instead of explode:

```
$qry0="SELECT DISTINCT id FROM users  ";
$res0=getData($qry0);
$data0 = array(); // initialize array first
while($row0=mysqli_fetch_array($res0))
{
    $data0[]      =   $row0['id'];  // create array like this
}

$array = implode(",", $data0); // use implode to convert array to string
```

Answer (score 0):

The explode() function breaks a string into an array.To break array into string you need to use implode()

```
$qry0="SELECT DISTINCT id FROM users  ";
$res0=getData($qry0);
$data0 = array();
while($row0=mysqli_fetch_array($res0))
{
    $data0[]      =   $row0['id'];  
}
$array = implode(",", $data0);
```